# How to set number of transaction per block in Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.4

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a HLF up and running, everything is OK. Thing is each 10 minute, I will sent at most 21 datas.

Without configuring, each ten minutes, I have 4 blocks created with respectively 6, 6, 5, 4 transactions.

I would like to configure block size to 21 when possible, so I would have 1 block / timestep

I have seen that this can be configured in `configtx.yaml`:

```
# Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 100

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 98 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
```

But I see here that MaxMessageCount is 100, it should be OK.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the **BatchTimeout** . BatchTimeout is the  amount of time to wait after the first transaction arrives for additional transactions before cutting a block. Decreasing this value will improve latency, but decreasing it too much may decrease throughput by not allowing the block to fill to its maximum capacity.

So you need to set the BatchTimeout in such a way that all of your transaction are falling in the same block before the timeout occurs.

Also check the **PreferredMaxBytes**, which the preferred size of block.

Comment: Ok, but this is my question, what setting should I put  ? I want a block with 20 messages, what is the relation between this field and the 20 messages I want ? In my case, messages are < 150 Bytes, current PreferredMaxBytes = 512KB, so I should be able to store 512000/150 =3413 message which is not the case, I can store 6 max.

Comment: then in this case you should update your batchtimeout. Batchtimout contribute to  the number of transaction in a batch.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I raised it from 500ms to 2sec, and it almost have all my tx inside ! Will raise it to 2.5sec Thanks

Comment: You need to choose the batch configurations wisely/according to the requirements because this also affects the TPS.